# Apache 2.4: Require expr: match %{var} with strings loaded from a file

Tags: regex, apache, ssl, require, expr

I have apache 2.4 with SSL validating client certificates. I'm trying to filter some users by the CN provided in the client cert. For that, I wrote a file with a list of permitted CN, with one CN per line.

The expression need to be like: true if `%{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN}` is inside `{file("/etc/httpd/users.txt")}`.

So, I want to use the "file" function to "Read contents from a file (including line endings, when present)" to validate the `%{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN}` from client certificate.

I tested it with: `%{} in {file()} and %{} =~ {file()}`, but it doesn't work.

I don't find any example on apache docs or googling. Does anyone knows how I can do this?